# Powershell - SQL Server - connectionstring in loop for multiple Instances

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, powershell

Thisis part of a bigger script which finds *DatabaseFiles* on a SQL Server machine (multiple instances).

Following should just return all files for 3 instances.

The server is called `V3000801` and there is one default instance + 2 named instances on there. It's ok with me if either default or named doesn't work I'll work around this alone (most likely create a flag and do default with another connection string).

`$SqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery()` just returns -1 which does not make any sense for me.

Thanks for the help

```
for($i=0;$i -lt $instances.Length;$i++){
  $SqlConnection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection;
  $Server= "V3000801\"+$instances[$i];
  $SqlConnection.ConnectionString = "Server = $server ; Database = master; Integrated Security = sspi;trusted_connection=true";
  $sqlQuery="SELECT physical_name FROM sys.master_files;";

  Write-Host $SqlConnection.ConnectionString;

  $SqlConnection.Open();
  $SqlCmd = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand;
  $SqlCmd.CommandText = $sqlQuery;
  $SqlCmd.Connection = $SqlConnection;
  $SqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
  $SqlConnection.Close();
}
```

Comment: can you post a sample of what is contained in `$instances`. it looks like you should be using `foreach` loop and the `$server` variable dosen`t look to be right.

Comment: I'm used to for-loops. Could have done the same with foreach. it seems like it connects so seems to be right.

Comment: ah ok so you are indexing into the `$instances` array ...for a moment i thought you were listing the whole array :)...anyway that part looks okay then.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `ExecuteReader` function for selects. `ExecuteNonQuery` is used for operations that do not return any results such as inserts, updates and deletes.

[Here](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Difference-between-ExecuteReader-ExecuteScalar-and-ExecuteNonQuery.aspx) is an example in .NET but it should be similar in PowerShell.

EDIT:

This code should work. I tried it out on my own environment (with a different server name).

```
for($i=0;$i -lt $instances.Length;$i++){
  $SqlConnection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection;
  $Server= "V3000801\"+$instances[$i];
  $SqlConnection.ConnectionString = "Server = $server ; Database = master; Integrated Security = sspi;trusted_connection=true";
  $sqlQuery="SELECT physical_name FROM sys.master_files;";

  Write-Host $SqlConnection.ConnectionString;

  $SqlConnection.Open();
  $SqlCmd = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand;
  $SqlCmd.CommandText = $sqlQuery;
  $SqlCmd.Connection = $SqlConnection;
  $reader = $SqlCmd.ExecuteReader();
          while ($reader.Read())
        {
           "pfad=" $reader["physical_name"];
        };
  $SqlConnection.Close();

}
```

Comment: I tried 

`$dr=$SqlCmd.ExecuteReader();

        while($dr.Read()){

            Write-Host "pfad=  + $dr["phyical_name"]";

       } 

       $SqlConnection.Close();`

just gives `System.Data.Common.DataRecordInternal` multiple times

Comment: I added an edited version of your code which I tested on my own environment. If that doesn't work then you might have an issue with your own environment. It might have something to do with you using $dr["phyical_name"] inside of a string.

Answer (score 0):

the link posted by @jody contains some good information
try:

```
$dr= $SqlCmd.ExecuteReader()
 while ($dr.Read())
{
  $dr.GetValue(0)
}
$sqlconnection.Close()
```